# Custom Buttons - Pulling through fields to a different record type (But same object)

Tags: custom-button, case, custom-link

Within the cases object we have two record types. One for general cases the other for complaints.

The button is on the page layout for cases, so normal client support operatives can escalate to 'complaints'.

What I cant seem to do however is pull through the account name & contact name from the original case - both are look up fields.

The code button currently looks like:

(URL)RecordType=012f0000000D2ZG&cas4_ilecell={!Case.AccountId}&Cas3_ilecell={!Case.ContactId}

The Accountid & Contactid are not showing errors but are not pulling through the results as expect.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are creating a button to prepopulate lookup fields, you need to provide two values - Id and Name. In your case the code will be

```
    RecordType=012f0000000D2ZG&cas4_lkid={!Case.AccountId}&cas4_mod={!Case.AccountName}&
    cas3_lkid={!Case.ContactId}&cas3_mod={!Case.ContactName}
```

Comment: Naren, you help is much appreciated.Thank you very much :)